# Not able to assign html value from javascript to an html element in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to assign a value like `<div> a value </div>` to an html element say textarea in chrome browser, but the value is not getting assigned. It works fine if i try to assign a plain text like `a value`

I am using this

```
$('#editor').html((content));
```

where content = `<div> a value </div>`

Please help me in solving this issue. Is it chrome not allowing to assign the html value or some thing different?

Comment: @user105165: You've asked 9 questions since May and you haven't accepted any. That kinds of discourage many of the regulars who'd be able to help. Do you need help on how to tag a question as answered?

Comment: Sorry for it, i will take care of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess with the `innerHTML` of a `textarea`, set its `value` instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, instead of setting the innerhtml i am now setting the value

Answer (score 0):

use this code to assign value or html to a div using jquery

```
$('#editor').append('<div> a value </div>');
```

or

```
content = '<div> a value </div>';
$('#editor').append(content);
```

Comment: yes i got the same problem but running this piece of code it works!!!!!!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
#test {width:100px; height:100px;}
  p { background:yellow; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <p>I would like to say: </p>
<script>
  $("p").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#editor").html($("<div>").text("<div>a value</div>").html());​
```

Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/MkBSP/1/